# How to award a bounty manually to two users?

Tags: support, bounty

I want to award a bounty manually to two users.

I have offered 50 bounty for a question. Now I want to offer 25 for each user who answered my question. How can I do that?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067/158667 ; last item. It's not possible to split a bounty between several answers.

Comment: I do this all the time.  Simply award one bounty; wait until it has gone through, and then award the sec on bounty.  It's that simple.  (the second bounty has to be twice as large as the previous, but so what?)

Answer (score -6):

It's a good point that SO should drop the silly "bounty doubles in size ..." mechanism.

Comment: How do you propose, then, that we prevent abuse?

Comment: Hey Cody - what sort of abuse?  Do you mean a limit ... person X can give three bounties on a question and that's it.

Comment: Using bounties to attract attention to your answers, earning you upvotes. It is possible to get more rep back than you spent on the bounties. ["Abusing" bounties for unlimited profit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/105275)

Comment: Fair enough, the answer there .. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/105639/155609 explains the rationale.  Seems silly to me, but that's fine!  I often put bounties on more than one "exemplary" answer -- but I'm guessing not many people do that.  Cheers

Comment: and .. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256183