# Rationale for limit of three Bounties

Tags: discussion, bounty, rate-limiting

I'm curious, what is the rationale for the limit of three active bounties at a time (ie, one user can only offer, have set up, three bounties at a time).

Comment: Well, it was raised [from 1 to 3](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61869/can-the-limit-on-simultaneous-bounties-be-relaxed) at some point. Reason stated in there still hold true: if there will be no limit, the site might get flooded with thousands of bounties, rendering the whole thing useless.

Comment: thanks for that link @shadow.  is there an official (or whatever?) statement somewhere of the rationale .. if so maybe pop it in as an answer?  well thanks.

Comment: No, didn't find any official statement. There's always the chance you will get one here. :-)

Comment: lol right on .. cheers

Comment: this limit is likely to prevent certain kinds of [ragequit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175402/a-user-ragequit-after-bountying-me-all-his-rep-and-im-kind-of-creeped-out-by-i)

Comment: @gnat - lol heh

Comment: Like other things, couldn't the limit be raised/waived for users of a certain reputation?

Comment: @gnat I think the limit has been around since before than incident.

Comment: dcow -- gnat was just joking.  John -- that's a GREAT IDEA, awesome idea

Comment: It seems to me that the natural limit is "how much reputation do you have to give away". Maybe you can further clip it with a rule: "if you have an open bounty, you can only offer another bounty if it is at least 25 points greater than your highest open bounty". That will automatically limit the number - but gives active high rep users the chance to offer as many as they like (after all they have earned the right to award bounties).

Comment: @Floris: So users with 100K+ rep could just offer as many bounties as they like (unless the increment is exponential).

Comment: @AmalMurali - no, they would have to offer 25, 50, 75, 100, ... in general N bounties would require you to give up `25 N (N+1) / 2` rep. So for 100 k, that's about 90 bounties. It's a lot of hard work to get to 100k. I say - if they want to spread the wealth with 90 bounties at once, let them have it. But yes - I did consider giving an exponential (say, doubling) rule. Then you would go 25, 50, 100, ... and a 100k user could have only ~13 bounties (if I did the math right in my head).

Answer (score -6):

There is no rationale for this. It's arbitrary.

Comment: This answer would be better if it cited some source, or at least provided a rational justification.

Comment: @CodyGray: There's no rationale for this answer. It's arbitrary.

Comment: I believe the simple fact is.  **This answer is correct.**  I get the feeling that, at best, the policy was "not thought out" - kind of random.  What a shame you can't give bounty points on this site.  You cut the gordian knot, shamoon.  Awesome.